# How to create a ring shape in Scene Builder?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

How can I create a ring shape in JavaFX Scene Builder or directly in FXML?

Comment: I'd go with creating an ImageView and setting a ring image to it. The transparency will be treated properly. What about that?

Comment: Thanks Math, I will try with that.

Answer (score 0):

In SceneBuilder, use Circle, and set fill to transparent, with strokes enabled. Adjust stroke width appropriately, and you will obtain a ring-like thing.

Comment: That is not seem to be good way as the stroke width is limited.